# How to make HTML navigation bar on the same line as the heading

Tags: html, html-lists, heading

How do I get my heading and navigation bar to both be on the same line? At the top of the page like you'll see most websites have?

Comment: Can you write what you have tried and what did not work as expected?

Comment: `float: left` or `position: absolute;` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: I would @Sjoerd2228888 if I could. I've tried countless times today and yesterday and decided to leave it because the editor won't allow it. All I've tried is to make the display inline and that doesn't seem to change anything, if that helps anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
    <div class="A">
    </div>
    <div class="B">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading {
      
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-color: red;

}

.A {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

.B {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I presume you have no experience with HTML / CSS?

Maybe you should document your question more...

Comment: I have some. I'm a student learning HTML and CSS at home and school and have some difficulties. Thank you though, I would show code if I was able to use the editor correctly...